# What the expected value of the number of girls that have a boy sitting to their left and to their right?

Tags: probability

4 boys and 6 girls sit randomly around a rounded table. what the expected value of the number of girls that have a boy sitting to their left and to their right?

I tried to define an indicator that gets the value 1 when we get the sequence: boy,girl,boy. but didn't know how to calculate the probability of getting 1.

any suggestion ?

Comment: Use Linearity of Expectation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $6$ girls, so the answer is $6$ times the probability that there are two boys  next to a particular girl; call her Amy.  There is a pool of 9 people who could sit next to Amy, two of whom end up as her seat-mates.  There are $\binom 9 2 = 36$ pairs of people who could be chosen, of which $\binom 4 2 = 6$ are boy-boy pairs.    The chance Amy gets 2 boys is thus  $6/36$.  Multiply this by $6$ to get the expected number of girls with a pair of boys, namely $36/36=1.$